# Google Map API shown blank map on bootstrap modal popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="showmap">click to show map</a>
<div class="hidden" style="display:none;">
<div id="mapp" style="height:300px; border:solid 1px #ccc;"></div>
</div>
<script>
$('.showmap').click(function(){
 $('.hidden').show();
});
</script>
<script>
function myMap(){
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapp'), {
          center: {lat: -4.131140, lng: 120.861760},
          zoom: 2,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDAuTFPlEcDfHzqTWBaSzfaGPWIJpyOUTk&callback=myMap"></script>
```

[image]

I have a problems while using google map, it will shown blank map on bootstrap modal popup like that image. How to fix it?

Comment: Any error in console? And also provide the js and html part ?

Comment: you need to give api key..

Comment: no sir, it work when i put that map outside the popup modal

Comment: @ReynaldHenryleo Please include all relevant information, That includes showing us your code, or even better, making a working snippet of the problem

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen here is the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the map after it has been loaded then it works just fine.

```css
.hidden div {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="showmap">click to show map</a>
<div class="hidden">
  <div id="mapp" style="height:300px; border:solid 1px #ccc;"></div>
</div>
<script>
  $('.showmap').click(function() {
    $('.hidden').removeClass("hidden")
  });

</script>
<script>
  function myMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapp'), {
      center: {
        lat: -4.131140,
        lng: 120.861760
      },
      zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });
  }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDAuTFPlEcDfHzqTWBaSzfaGPWIJpyOUTk&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Comment: @ReynaldHenryleo Try this

Comment: Andersen ok tq sir